# Maximum key size in PBE?

Tags: java, encryption, password-encryption

In Java I see each encryption type has a maximum key size like AES-256, DES-128, 3DES-128 and so on. In PBE we are entering the key and its modified by salt. I would like to know what can be the maximum key size for PBE? Is it dependent on salt ? Is it dependent on Iterator?

Answer (score 1):

PBE (password based encryption) is used to encrypt data with password, and is based on underlying encryption algorithm (i.e. AES, DES, Blowfish, etc).
So you can give it any password, and it will be processed, hashed, HMACed, whatever else, and result is reduced to match the underlying encryption algorithm key size.

Comment: So In this case is it more secure than algorithms like AES, DES, Blowfish?

Comment: No. It uses the same AES, DES, Blowfish. The reason to use PBE is to obtain key from password.